# Android debug on devices which connect to remote server

Tags: android, adb, android-debug

I have a remote server which connect some android devices, how can I debug on them from my local laptop, with user interaction enabled?

Comment: do you have network connection from you local computer to the remote server where you have connected your android devices ?

Comment: @Rilwan Of course, but I would not prefer a remote desktop solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically you need to forward the adb client port[remote pc where you connncted your android device to you local PC where you are interested to work with adb. There are many solutions -

1. **use ssh or rsh or similar remote shell programs**

Install rsh/ssh server in remote PC, install rsh/ssh client local pc. Then you can directly call `rsh remoteserverIp adb shell blah blah`. Easiest solution without any coding, only `next>next>install` for rsh/ssh server is needed :)

2. **Connect to remote PC via vnc or rdp**

This you are not interested in.

3. **Make your own script or program to forward adb client port on remote pc to your local pc.**

This can easily done in python/Java. you need to run a server in remote PC which will forward adb client port from remote PC to you local PC over your network connection. fortunately there is a handy solution for this .try this https://bitbucket.org/chabernac/adbportforward/wiki/Home